# The remote name could not be resolved: 'maps.googleapis.com'

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I have an `asp.net` web application that uses Google Maps. Everything has been running fine for quite some time. All of a sudden yesterday, no calls to Google API would process. I assume we reached a query limit but upon checking, all quota totals were `0`. I then realized we were not including our API Key in the requests. I added the appropriate API key and the maps came back online. However, I still cannot `GeoCode` a address using the following:

```
maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=(PROPERTY-ADDRESS)&key=(OUR-KEY)
```

returns:

> The remote name could not be resolved: 'maps.googleapis.com'

We get the same error when trying to use:

```
maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=(LOCATION1)&destinations=(LOCATION2)&units=imperial&key=(OUR-KEY)
```

However all calls to:

```
maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=(OUR-KEY)
```

work fine.

This code has worked fine for a long time, with no modifications.
We are on a dedicated server, using the same IP, However the site does run through `Incapsula` (Not sure if that makes a difference)

I already added:

```
 <system.net>
        <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
        </defaultProxy>
   </system.net>
```

but this did not help.

The error: **The remote name could not be resolved** makes it seem like a DNS issue, but the server is online and can resolve `maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js` without any problem.

Comment: Like the one that you think it is DNS problem, then you can try the suggestion [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/2005675.aspx?Getting+google+remote+name+could+not+be+resolved+maps+googleapis+com+). Check [this](http://support.bintube.com/entries/21699126-Fixing-DNS-Errors-Remote-name-could-not-be-resolved) for more information.

Also from this [thread](https://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/15285/error-trying-to-use-googlemapsgeocodingapi/), make sure that your firewall is not blocking your request.

Comment: have you solved the issue ?

Comment: am facing same problem and can't literally get it. please help.

Comment: @KENdi can you please elaborate what actually is preventing it to access the url.